# php7.2でpeclコマンドを使いたい

Tags: php, amazon-linux

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum install -y \
    curl \
    git \
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-devel \
    httpd \
    mysql \
    gcc \
    vim \
    mod_ssl
sudo wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
sudo yum install -y \
    php72 \
    php72-php \
    php72-php-devel \
    php72-php-mbstring \
    php72-php-opcache \
    php72-php-soap \
    php72-php-mysqlnd \
    php72-php-pear
```

AmazonLinux2で上記のようにphp72-php-pearをインストールしたのですがpeclコマンドがないと言われてしまいます試しにpecl7,pecl72もありませんでした。
peclコマンドを使いたいのですがどうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: `find / -name pecl` の結果はどうなりますか？

Comment: `/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/bin/pecl`
`/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/share/doc/pecl`
`/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/share/tests/pecl`

Answer (score 1):

理由は分かりませんが `pecl` が `/usr/bin/` に作られないようです。

`php72-php-pear` パッケージは [Software Collections であり](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)、`/opt/remi/php72/` 以下に環境を作っており、PECL 自体は `/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/bin/pecl` に存在しています。

ワークアラウンドではありますが、この `pecl` を使ってあげればとりあえず動くようです。つまり、`ln -s` でシンボリックリンク `/usr/bin/pecl` を作るか、PATH を設定して `/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/bin/` を含むようにすると、コマンドを見つけてくれるようになります。

Remi's RPM Repository の[フォーラム](https://forum.remirepo.net/)で聞けば、何かしら理由が分かるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

個人的には Software Collections のパッケージは `alternatives` で管理するのが作法かなと思ってるんですが、例えば次のようにすれば `/usr/bin/pecl` が作成されると思います。

```
$ sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/pecl pecl /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/bin/pecl 1
```